# Mass Effect 3 Motivational Speech

Tags: mass-effect-3

I'm trying to find, for quite some time already, the motivational speech made by Commander Shepard in London, before the final assault, in Mass Effect 3.

If possible, complete, with both Paragon and Renegade variations

Comment: Here are links to videos of the [paragon](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=GLJLhfNvEaI) and [renegade](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=NmMvHLKO9d0) speeches. I'll try to transcribe them for a real answer when I have chance.

Comment: General reference "questions" are discouraged.

Comment: This is one of the Stack Exchange communities in which posting guidelines have the weakest of the comprehension foundations. But, unfortunately I can't counter-argue so i won't be bitching around because just you think my question is not in fact a question.

Comment: https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Mass_Effect_3 has some quotes from that speech. I don't know if it's every variation, but every word I heard in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sma9u-uQBi4) is there.